# How do I prevent Android Studio from deleting Flutter imports before I used them?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am having trouble with Android Studio immediately deleting my Dart/Flutter imports, especially if I click outside of Android Studio.

For example, I pasted these from another file into an empty file to refactor my code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
```

Before I can use the imports, Android Studio automatically deletes them.  I went into Preferences > General > Auto Import.  For Dart it has the line "Update imports on paste: Ask".  I tried changing this to the other options of Never or Always and that didn't work.  I also tried to change the Java settings (Currently under Java, Optimize imports on the fly is unchecked for me).

I don't mind that unused imports are deleted.  I just don't like it that I basically have to create the code that uses the imports before the import will stay put at the top of the file without Android Studio auto-deleting them.

P.S. My current version of Android Studio is 4.2.1.

Answer (score 3):

Unticking 'Organize imports on save' in 'File | Settings | Languages & frameworks | Flutter | Editor | Format code on save' works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck **Format code on save** in: **File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Flutter**

Comment: My version of Android Studio does not have File | Settings.  I think I have to go into Android Studio | Preferences.  My version of Android Studio appears to be 4.2.1.  I just downloaded it this week.

Answer (score 0):

Just Uncheck this checkbox `File` -> `Settings` -> `Languages & Frameworks` -> `Flutter` -> `Editor` -> `Organize imports on save`

[image]